# How can I find the value of specific Spark configuration property?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How can I find the value of a spark configuration in my spark code?

For example, I would like to find the value of spark.sql.shuffle.partitions and reference this in my code.

The following code will return all values:-

`spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()`

How can I retrieve a single configuration setting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this.

```
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")
'200' # returns default value here
```