# PySpark how to check if Adaptive Query Execution is enabled or not?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I understand that in Spark 3.something it is enabled by default (I think default true for 3.2 but default false for 3.0?)

I've read that `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", true)` enables it but is there a method or function that tells me whether it is currently on/off?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the value of specific Spark configuration property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55935209/how-can-i-find-the-value-of-specific-spark-configuration-property)

Answer (score 3):

Found it:
`spark.conf.get("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled")`